# PlotlyError: The `figure_or_data` positional argument must be `dict`-like, `list`-like, or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.Figure -

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I'm having issues with a the error code above. I am creating two stacked bar charts that should be aligned side by side in streamlit using plotly. the first stacked bar chart is displayed with no issue but the second wont display. What am i doing wrong?

```
from turtle import shape
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import os
from wordcloud import WordCloud , STOPWORDS
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots



st.markdown('### Sentiment breakdown of gender')

col1, col2,col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20  = st.columns(20)

with col1:

    
    df_2 = data_2.groupby(["label","extra_author_attributes.gender"]).size().reset_index(name='counts')
    #st.write(df_test)
    fig_3 = px.bar(df_2, x="label", y="counts", color="extra_author_attributes.gender", 
    labels={
                        "label": "Sentiment",
                        "counts": "Count",
                        "extra_author_attributes.gender": "Gender"
                    },
    text_auto=True)
    st.plotly_chart(fig_3)

with col20:
    
    df_3 = data_2.groupby(["label","extra_author_attributes.gender"]).size().reset_index(name='counts')
    #st.write(df_test)
    fig_4 = px.bar(df_3, x="extra_author_attributes.gender", y="counts", color="label", 
    labels={
                        "label": "Sentiment",
                        "counts": "Count",
                        "extra_author_attributes.gender": "Gender"
                    },
    text_auto=True), 
    st.plotly_chart(fig_4)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with 20 columns? I think you have so much columns. Use only 2 or 3 columns to see whether it displays the chart or not.

Comment: @JamiuShaibu That was to align them side by side in streamlit .I tried that, also tried removing the columns and had no luck.

Comment: I don' know how big your charts are but it will still not be appropriate to have that much columns for chart.  How many charts do you have to display?

Comment: @JamiuShaibu That makes sense, i removed them but I'm still seeing the same error code. I have to display 7 charts in total.

Comment: Did you remember to change `with col20:` and well? if yes and is still doesn't work, try to display `fig_4` outside of the columns to confirm that your chart works, because I don't really know what your `df_3` holds, let me know whether  `fig_4` works outside the column.

Comment: @JamiuShaibu Yeah I removed the columns and i still have the same error. Sorry i forgot to post what it holds. basically i have a csv file with the data.  data_2 is a the csv file. df_3 holds two columns in the data set and counts the values so i can then create the visualisation. lmk if that makes any sense.